# how to create a variable which could accept only certain values?

Tags: scala

I want to create a variable which represents success or failure.

Is `Enumeration` the best way to do such a thing?

```
object Result extends Enumeration {
  val Fail = Value(0)
  val Success = Value(1) 
}
```

My use case is that the variable would be part of a case class.

```
case class JsonResult (result: Result)
```

This JSON would be sent to client.Eg

```
{
result: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sealed traits frequently turn to be out more flexible for this kind of thing:

```
sealed trait MySpecialResult
object MySpecialFailure extends MySpecialResult
object MySpecialSuccess extends MySpecialResult
```

This is more flexible, because it is much easier to change `MySpecialFailure` and `MySpecialSuccess` to classes, for example if you want to attach some error message to the failure case, you can replace it by a case class:

```
case class MySpecialFailure(message: String) extends MySpecialResult
```

Maybe you could look at `scala.util.{Either, Left, Right}` and at `Try` with the concrete subclasses `Success` and `Failure` for inspiration.